# Git Client with UI on a Debian system

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, git, github

I known using `git` on the command line is the preferred method by a lot of Linux users.

But has somebody have successfully installed and used a Git Client with GUI on  Debian Based System? (to be precise it is a Raspberry PI 2 with raspbian distro)

I am asking that question, because I didn't find any answer on Web, and a GUI is a most **convenient** way to manage conflict for example.

As I am using l low powered device, I am also looking for a ligweight client of course

Best regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git` itself provides a GUI, which in Debian derivatives, including Raspbian, is packaged as [`git-gui`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/git-gui). Install that, and you’ll be able to run `git gui` to perform most operations. You can also install [`gitk`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gitk) to explore repositories in a GUI.

To resolve merge conflicts, I quite like [Meld](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/meld), but that pulls in part of GNOME so it doesn’t quite count as lightweight!